# Implementing post requests using okhttp

Tags: android, websocket, http-post, okhttp

Hi I've literally read all the recipes about post and get request for okhttp, but i cant really grasp what am i doing. I am trying to send data over using these codes

```
//POST network request
    private void sendReq(int a) {
        Log.d(" ", "Sending data to Arduino....");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(RequestBody.create(JSON, createJSON(a)))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });
    }

    private String createJSON(int a) {
        return "{\"motor\": [" + a + "]}";
    }
```

That will supposedly be controlling a motor attached on arduino/esp8266, but i dont know if i am sending it right.

```
right.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                text.setText("Right");
                sendReq(1);
```

This is what i used to call the sendReqmethod, i think by putting a value of '1' it will send an integer which will be i need to read the data on esp8266.
Though I am seeing a successful connection, I cannot see if it does send it over.

Comment: I suggest you to use okttp logging interceptor to check what you send and receive from android monitor, check the link https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Ok i will try and implement that, but do you think I am using the createJSON method right? supposedly my url is http://192.168.254.101/, it will become http://192.168.254.101/motor1, that is what i noticed when i am using the HTTPUrlConnection